# A script which runs multiple scripts within it. Need to pass the list of all the scripts executed before it to the last executed script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a script and within that script I am calling several other scripts.

Now I have a requirement where I need to get the list of all the scripts that have been run as I need to audit these in the database.

I have tried the history command but it does not seem to be working.

Can anyone propose any approaches that would help me.

Thank you!

Comment: The history command simply lists your bash history, as these scripts weren't executed from bash - they won't be there.  How many scripts are executed first?  Is it deterministic, or is there some recursion/etc involved?

Comment: There is no recursion as such. So I have a script A and with in Script A, script b, script c and script d are called. So to script d i need to pass in the list of all the previously executed scripts which in turn puts this info in a audit table. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Are script b and script c hard coded into script a?  Or are they paramaterized in some (any) way?
If so, where does script a get scripts b and c from?  a text file? command line arguments?

Is there a reason you cannot just turn ECHO on in script A, then pass it's output to script D?  that way script D can log the input it receives and you'll have the output of whatever commands script A runs?

Comment: Yes Script b and script c are hardcoded into script A. Can you show me one example when you say I can do an ECHO on script A. I'll try it out.

Comment: With script `a` serving as a *wrapper* for both scripts `b` and `c`, you will either need to keep a running list of the functions called (e.g. declare `funcs=""` at the top of `a`, then within each function `func="${funcs} fncname"` (with no array capability in POSIX shell)) or write the function name out to a temporary file as they are called. Either way you have a running list of the functions called at any point in script `a`.